# On integral closedness of the multiplication of a monomial integrally closed ideal with the homogeneous maximal ideal

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, monomial-ideals, integral-extensions

Consider the monomial ideal $I=(x^d, y^az^{d-a})$ in $\mathbb C [x,y,z]$ where $1\le a\le d-1$ are integers. Let $\mathfrak m=(x,y,z)$. Let $J=\overline I$ be the integral closure of $I$.

If $J\mathfrak m$ is not integrally closed, then is it true that $(\overline {J+\mathfrak m^t })\mathfrak m$ is not integrally closed for some integer $t\ge 1$ ?

I think either $t=d+1$ or $t=d+2$ or $t=d+3$ should work, but I'm not sure.

The motivation for my question is: from the knowledge of an integrally closed monomial ideal $J$ such that $J\mathfrak m$ is not integrally closed, I'm trying come up with an integrally closed monomial $\mathfrak m$-primary ideal $L$ such that $L\mathfrak m$ is not integrally closed.

Please help.

Comment: One potentially silly clarification: do you mean to fix $a$, or have it range over $1,\cdots,d-1$? That is, do you mean something like $(x^3,yz^2)$ or $(x^3,yz^2,y^2z)$?

Comment: @KReiser: I want $I$ to be generated by two elements i.e. $\mu(I)=2$, so your first option ... but if you have any ideas for the second option (so $\mu(I)=d$) , I'd be willing to look at that too

Comment: Just have a quick question: if $I$ is generated by $2$ elements then what is the difference between $J$ and $I$?